# Checking multi window support

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, multi-window

I've a problem with checking is device supports Mutli Window Mode. I'm using this function to check it `isInMultiWindowMode()` but it've added in API 24, and when i'm runs my app on device with lower api version it cause an exception. There is any replacement for this function for lower api versions?

Comment: If it doesn't exist in lower API's how can you check it?

Answer (score 2):

> There is any replacement for this function for lower api versions?

Not in the Android SDK. There is no multi-window mode (from the Android SDK's standpoint) prior to API Level 23. And, for whatever reason, Google elected not to add `isInMultiWindowMode()` to `ActivityCompat`, perhaps because they cannot support the corresponding event (`onMultiWindowModeChanged()`).

So, here's a free replacement method:

```
public static boolean isInMultiWindowMode(Activity a) {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    return false;
  }

  return a.isInMultiWindowMode();
}
```

Add that to some utility class somewhere and call it as needed.

Also note that `isInMultiWindowMode()` suffers from [a race condition](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/06/07/isinmultiwindowmode-race-condition.html) that makes it unreliable, IMHO.

Comment: Multiwindow support and the isInMultiWindowMode() were added in Android N (API 24)

Answer (score 0):

What @CommonsWare explained is true, it is a race condition. Hence, `isInMultiWindowMode()` will give actual result if you call it from inside post method:

```
    View yourView = findViewById(R.id.yourViewId);
    yourView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            boolean actualResult = isInMultiWindowMode();
        }
    });
```